# Как правильно модифицировать возможности парсера для загрузки фотографий нужных товаров из категорий и чтобы код отработал без ошибок

Tags: php, парсер

Здравствуйте можете помочь разобрать понять как изменить логику скрипта или добавить в него еще одну функцию парсинга фотографий с сайта донора. Для самого парсинга информации используется скрипт:

```
<?php

global $postCount;
include_once 'db.php';
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

function curlGetPage($url, $referer = '
https://google.com/')
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    return $response;

}

function parseAndInsertData($html)
{
    global $db;

    foreach ($html->find('*[class="col-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 us-item"]') as $element) {
        $img = $element->find('*[class="img-fluid oct-lazy"]',0);
        $link = $element->find('.us-module-img a', 0);
        $priceElem = $element->find('*[class="us-module-price-actual"]',0);



        $price = $priceElem->plaintext;
        $trimmedP = ltrim($price, "$");


       // $priceJIS = float($price);
        $post = [
            'img' => $img->src,
            'title' => $img->alt,
            'link' => $link->href,
            'price' => $trimmedP,
        ];

        $priceN = isset($post['price']) ? floatval($post['price']) : 0;

        $priceCH = floatval($price);
        $db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO posts (`title`, `img`, `link`, `price`) 
        VALUES('{$post['title']}', '{$post['img']}', '{$post['link']}', {$priceN})");

        echo "Step cycle:" . PHP_EOL. $postCount;

        $price = $priceElem->plaintext;
        echo "Original price: " . $price . PHP_EOL;

        //$priceCH = floatval($price);
        echo "Parsed price: " . $priceN . PHP_EOL;

    }
}

//$page = curlGetPage('https://***/zaryadni-prystroyi');
//$html = str_get_html($page);

$url = 'https://***/zaryadni-prystroyi?page=1';
$page = curlGetPage($url);
$html = str_get_html($page);

// Parse and insert data from the first page
parseAndInsertData($html);

$pagenavi = $html->find('ul.pagination',0);
//$lastPageLink = $pagenavi[0]->lastChild();
$lastLi = $pagenavi->find('li', -1);
$lastAnchor = $lastLi->find('a', 0);

if ($lastAnchor && $lastAnchor->hasAttribute('href')) {
    // Get the value of the "href" attribute and extract the page number (assuming it's the last part of the URL)
    $lastHref = $lastAnchor->getAttribute('href');
    $pageNumber = intval(basename($lastHref));
    $schetchik = $pageNumber + 1;

    // Output the parsed page number as an integer
   // echo "Last page number: " . $pageNumber;

    for ($i = 1; $i >= $schetchik ; $i++) {
        // Set the correct referer for pagination


        $referer = "https://optitrade.dp.ua/zaryadni-prystroyi/?page=$i";

        // Fetch the page content
        $page = curlGetPage($referer, $referer);
        $html = str_get_html($page);

        // Parse and insert data from the current page
        parseAndInsertData($html);

        usleep(1500000);

        // Optionally, you can add a limit to the number of pages to parse
        if ($i > 100) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
else{echo "Last link not found or doesn't have the 'href' attribute.";}
?>
```

Дальше есть скрипт с необходимой функцией, которую по логике нужно объявить где-то в блоке после использования Курла. То есть не могу понять почему сам парсер выгружает в мою базу все записи с сайта донора когда у меня по идее должно с помощью

```
<?php
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

function parseImagesWithClass($url, $targetClass, $localDirectory) {
    $html = file_get_html($url);

    if ($html !== false) {
        $elements = $html->find($targetClass);

        if (!is_dir($localDirectory)) {
            mkdir($localDirectory, 0777, true);
        }

        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            $imgElement = $element->find('img', 0);
            if ($imgElement) {
                $imgSrc = $imgElement->src;

                // Ensure the image URL is absolute
                if (strpos($imgSrc, 'http') === false) {
                    $imgSrc = $url . $imgSrc;
                }

                $imgFilename = $localDirectory . '/' . basename($imgSrc);

                // Download the image and save it to the local directory
                file_put_contents($imgFilename, file_get_contents($imgSrc));
            }
        }

        $html->clear();
        unset($html);
    } else {
        echo "Failed to fetch HTML from the URL: $url";
    }
}

// Sample usage:
$url = 'https://example.com/products'; // Replace with the URL of the product page
$targetClass = '.product-image'; // Replace with the class that contains the product images
$localDirectory = 'images'; // Replace with the local directory where images will be saved
parseImagesWithClass($url, $targetClass, $localDirectory);
?>
```

Я так понимаю что по логике эту функцию `parseImagesWithClass` вторую нужно вызывать после `parseAndInsertData($html)` чтобы везде сохранились доступы к объектам и они не перепутали друг другу содержимое.
Извините за столь сложный вопрос.

И еще непонятно почему не срабатывает условия досрочного завершения цикла с условием

```
if ($i > 100) {
    break;
}
```